# open Truecrypt container with password xor keyfile

Tags: truecrypt

i am using a truecrypt container on a flash drive, which I back up periodically. Last days the container crashed and I lost some important data. This made me think about my backup strategy and I think it might be smarter to sync the difference when mount the USB at home.

I would like to script the mount and rsync of the drive when it will be plugged. for this I don't want to put the password to open in the script. when i am not in my apartment, I'd prefer the usage of a password instead of the key file.
Is it possible to open a truecrypt (or veracrypt,...) with a password when i am outside and with a key file at home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technically: maybe yes**
The password and any keyfiles are mixed together to derive the container key.

`PW X KF = CK` ("X" being the mixing algorithm.)

The mixing algorithm is not that great. -- For example [there is a way to construct keyfiles](https://www.privacy-cd.org/downloads/truecrypt_7.0a-analysis-en.pdf), that don't change the resulting container key at all. -- So I guess it might be feasible that you could start with a password of your choice and then run a little script that generates a keyfile from that password.

So that
`No-Password X KF = CK`
and
`PW X No-Keyfile = CK`

So this would work if you input either PW or KF. (But annoyingly *not* if you input *both*.)

**Practically: Why bother?**
But to what end?
I don't think you would gain anything security-wise.
If you have the keyfile lying around somewhere and that gets copied that's just as bad as having the password lying around and that being copied.

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be done.  Once you specify encryption with a keyfile and/or password, you have to use them for any decryption.  If security is important to you, you can only specify encryption done with a keyfile **and** a password, and use them both whether you're outside or at home.